# Circuit Panel Box Sunk Into Drywall

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, circuit-breaker

Recently doing a project on a shed. My friend bought the house a few years ago with an unfinished shed and was able to have some family members to go and put up drywall.
Unfortunately it was definitely an amateur job. They just put up mud on the wall panels, didn't mud the ceiling or box or trim the window panels. They even painted the walls with just one coat of mud! Most of the outlets were sunk, which required extender bits to hold flush.
I'm finished fixing the mistakes, however I'm stuck on trying to remedy the circuit panel box. It is currently sitting just past the drywall.
All I want to achieve is making sure the drywall is not exposed.
Would a second door hinge do the trick?
Would the metal touching metal cause problems?
Would I have to unscrew and try to reseat the box?
Do I have to take the entire drywall section out?
Is there a quick and cheap solution to this problem?
Any suggestions would be appreciated.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 11):

Only 2 real options here.

One is to cut back the drywall *more* and create a tasteful wooden trim around the subpanel. The panel cover must be removable without tools.

The other is to pull the panel off the wall and pull it out so its surface is flush with the drywall, then purchase a *flush mount* deadfront cover for that panel.

This looks like the deadfront cover that is on there now is a *surface mount* one, designed for the back of the panel to be even with the wall surface and the panel sticking out 4 inches or so.  The flush-mount cover will extend beyond the edge of the panel by 1/2" or so to coverup the ragged edge of the drywall.

Panels are not allowed to be inset slightly into drywall the way junction boxes are.

Comment: Could OP put a door / faux-cupboard in front, mounted onto the drywall's face ?   Not sure of legality if the panel is hidden from view.

Comment: @Criggie Sure, I don't see why not.

Comment: After taking a closer look at the box, I took Harper's suggestion and took the panel out and reseated it farther out of the drywall. As you can see, the stud on the left, and i was able to secure it with the front panel just past the drywall.  My final plan is to use some L-Corner Beads to trim and finish the edges, and use an extra sliver of drywall to fill that top gap.  Got a Vacation coming soon and plan to finish mudding the ceilings and windows, so using the L-beads might be the trick to make it look good.  Will post pics when i finish.

Comment: Before you do too much drywall work, contact a GE dealer with the model number of that panel (or cover, possibly) and see if they can sell you a flush mount version of that cover.  That will coverup at least 1/2" of drywall around the fringe.  It's what they're for.  Also, no one adding a circuit to a panel ever cried and complained that the last installer left them a tasteful cabinet door or easily removed panel immediately above the serice panel. Food for thought.

Comment: Not the greatest job, but for an first time DIY job, I think it turned out pretty good.  All my friend wanted was to make any exposed drywall was covered up.  Once we prime the walls, I think it will turn out OK.  Any comments or critiques are appreciated. [![enter image description here][1]][1]


[![enter image description here][2]][2]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/BwsTt.jpg
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2hkU0.jpg